# Vim Configuration: How to expand tabs only when saving?

Tags: vim

I love tabs, and prefer it to spaces in indentation.

But I'd like to transform tabs into 4-space groups when saving files. (Because the file may be opened and edited in other environments) And of course, those generated spaces should be converted back to tabs if I open the file again. (Assume that there are no 4 contiguous spaces in the original text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Zsolt Botykai's answer, you could try using `retab!`, which attempts to replace spaces with tabs where appropriate. This seemed to work quite well when I just tried it, but I got a few erroneous tabs. I suppose it depends how good your assumption is that there no other sequences of 4 spaces other than expanded tabs.

**HOWEVER...** this all seems like a risky business. In my experience, when there are coding/encoding standards such as these, it is always easiest to adhere to them from the start. "Fixing-up" the file in this way is asking for trouble.

I think Vim does a good job of emulating tab-like behaviour while using only spaces. Have you tried using `smarttab` and `expandtab`?

Comment: The combination you proposed is just what I need!

Answer (score 2):

Well in your `.vimrc`:

```
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
fun MyRetab()
    set expandtab
    retab
    set noexpandtab
endfun
au FileWritePre *.YOURFILEEXTENSION call MyRetab()
```

But I don't know what you mean by *"those spaces should be still recognized as tabs if I open the file again."*

If you write a file spaces instead of tabs, well it can't be undone easily AFAIK. **EDIT**: see the [super retab wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Super_retab) for undoing it!

**NOTE** if you have tab(s) in your source's string contents this will replace that as well!

Comment: I mean that if I reopen the file, the spaces generated from tabs should be back to tabs in edit area.

Comment: Thx! That's the exact answer to my original question. But I prefer a safer way proposed by Prince Goulash.